# Oracle DB 11g cluster algorithm in sql or pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hey, 
I´m currently struggling with a problem in Oracle corresponding to a custom cluster algorithm. 
 I have a table like this:

**Product** 
ID  Prop1 Prop2 Prop3 
------------------------------ 
1    1001  1002  1003 
2    1001  2002  2003 
3    3001  1002  3003 
4    4001  4002  2003 
5    5001  5002  5003 
6    6001  6002  6003 
7    7001  7002  7003 
8    8001  7002  8003 
9    9001  1002  4003

Each product has different properties (Prop1, Prop2, Prop3). All products which share a common property should finally be in the same cluster. In this example we would have the following clusters: 
 
{1,2,3,4,9}, {5}, {6}, {7,8} 

 
Product 1 and 2 share Prop1, product 1, 3 and 9 share Prop2, product 2 and 4 share Prop3. Union of all products give us {1,2,3,4,9}. And so on.

What I´ve done so far:

```
select listagg(id, ',') within group (order by prop1) "clusterIdsProp1"
from clustertest
group by prop1
having count(prop1) > 1;
```

This gives me the productIds which builds a cluster with more than one item.

**Table A** 
clusterIdsProp1 
1,2

**Table B** 
clusterIdsProp2 
1,3,9 
7,8

Now I´m trying to merge these intermediate results to extend the current cluster. Is there a way in Oracle to merge lists if they share a common item?

My aim is to merge these two tables in a way that my result table looks like this:

**Merged Table** 
clusterIds 
1,2,3,9 
7,8 

I´m using Oracle 11g. Thanks in advance. 
Let me know if you have other suggestions to solve the whole "cluster" problem.
Cheers.

Comment: What data type are the lists - varchar2 with commas-separated values? Which is a bad way to store data. And what would you do if the second row in table B also included a value from the A record, e.g. 2,7,8? What if an ID appeared in more that one row, in either source table?

Comment: i added some information about the whole task. hope it´s clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer for my problem. Unfortunately performance is very bad for large datasets. So if anyone has a better approach, please let me know.

```sql
--step 1
--if there are more properties just adapt 'or-clauses'
with edges as (
  --determines all (non transitive) edges
  select ct1.id as edge1, ct2.id as edge2
  from clustertest ct1, clustertest ct2
  where ct1.id != ct2.id and ct1.id < ct2.id and (ct1.prop1 = ct2.prop1 or ct1.prop2 = ct2.prop2 or ct1.prop3 = ct2.prop3 /* add further properties here*/)),

-- step 2  
tc(edge1, edge2) as (
  -- calculates the transitive closure
  -- Anchor member.
  select edge1, edge2
  from edges
  union
  -- Recursive member.
  select e1.edge1, e2.edge2
  from   edges e1, edges e2
  where  e2.edge1 = e1.edge2),
-- still step 2   
correctEdges as(
  --removes unneccessary edges
  select edge1, edge2 from tc
  where edge1 not in (select tc1.edge1
                      from tc tc1, tc tc2
                      where tc1.edge1 = tc2.edge2
                      group by tc1.edge1, tc1.edge2)
  or edge2 not in (select tc1.edge2
                   from tc tc1, tc tc2
                   where tc1.edge1 =  tc2.edge2
                   group by tc1.edge1, tc1.edge2))

-- step 4   
-- group by edge1 and build final clusters
select concat(edge1, concat(',', listagg(edge2, ',') within group (order by edge1, edge2))) as clusterIds
  from correctEdges
  group by edge1
  -- step 5
  union
  --add 'single' clusters (only one item)
  select to_char(id) as clusterIds
  from clusterTest
  minus
    -- step 3
    (select to_char(edge1)
     from correctEdges
     group by edge1
     union
     select to_char(edge2) as edge1
     from correctEdges
     group by edge2);
```

Short explanation for each step:

1. Which Ids have at least one common property with another product? We store the Ids which results in (undirected) edges. It is possible to add other properties by adapting the 'or-clause' in edges (see SQL-Statement).
2. We calculate the transitive closure for this edges and remove duplicate ones which occur in another representation.
3. Calculate all Ids which occur at least in one edge and remove them from the whole set of Ids.
4. Group by column edge1 and do a concat from edge1 with all corresponding values.
5. In a final step we merge these results with all 'single clusters' which only contain one item / product.